# How to calculate this factorial

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n, v;
    printf("Please enter a value from 39 to 59: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Please enter a value from 3 to 7: \n");
    scanf("%d", &v);

}
```

When I got those values from user, how can I perform this factorial calculation:

```
n! / ((n-v)! * v!))
```

I've tried different data types but apparently none can hold the result.

For example: n = 49, v=6. The result is: 13,983,816, but how can I go about getting it?

Comment: Pleas post how you've tried to calculate your equation, not how you get the parameters.

Comment: You could use libraries such as [GMP Bignum library](https://gmplib.org/) to represent large numbers.

Comment: If you need exact results, you'll need to use some extended-precision integer library. If not, floating-point has enough range, but the results will be inexact.

Comment: @thelaws I tried n = 39, v = 6. (39*38*37*36*35*34) / 6!. Could not find the right data type to hold the numerator value.

Comment: @BlueMoon: I've seen a lot of suggestions regarding that, but i'm looking for something different and easier. Thanks aw.

Comment: If you need exact results, you can use an extended-precision integer library like GMP or you can switch to another language. If you don't need exact results, please say so.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I just need  this value: 13,983,816 when n=49, v=6. Then divid it by 1..store the result in a double.

Comment: Dividing by `.1` doesn't make sense; just convert it. You *still* haven't told us whether you need exact results. If you don't, you can do all the calculations in floating-point, with some loss of precision; does that meet your requirements or not? But it looks like the final result will probably fit in an integer; it's the intermediate results that are too big. In that case, there are probably ways to perform the multiplications and divisions in a different order, so you never actually have to calculate `49!`. I suggest you update your question to make that clearer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You're right about the intermediate result. That's what I want to achieve. No, I don't need the exact result. For example: when doing 1/13,983,816, 0.0000000715112384202 is the one that I need to get. Yes, I know there are ways to work it around, but I can't seem to find them.

Comment: You don't need exact results (why didn't you say so earlier?). So do all the calculations in floating-point. The large number you need to compute is `59!`, which is about `1.3e80`, which fits easily into type `double`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: My mistake. Thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Comment: I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment, you've finally said that you don't need exact results.

Just use floating-point. The largest intermediate result you'll need to handle is `59!`, which is about `1.3868e80`; type `double` is more than big enough to hold that value.

Write a function like:

```
double factorial(int n);
```

(I presume you know how to implement it) and use that.

If you're going to be doing a lot of these calculations, you might want to cache the results by storing them in an array. If you define an array like:

```
double fact[60];
```

then you can store the value of `N!` in `fact[N]` for N from 0 to 59 -- and you can fill the entire array in about the time it would take to compute `59!` just once. Otherwise, you'll be doing several dozen floating-point multiplications and divisions on each calculation -- which is trivial if you do it once, but could be significant if you do it, say, thousands or millions of times.

If you needed exact results, you could use an extended integer library like GNU MP, as others have suggested. Or you could use a language (like Python, for example) that has built-in support for arbitrary-length integers.

Or you could probably perform the multiplications and divisions in an order that avoids overflow; I don't know exactly how to do that, but since `n! / ((n-v)! * v!))` is a common formula I strongly suspect that work has already been done.

Answer (score 5):

You're best bet is to ditch the naive factorial implementations, usually based on recursion, and switch to one that returns the natural log of gamma function.

The gamma function is related to factorial: `gamma(n) = (n-1)!`

Best of all is [natural log of gamma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html), because you can rewrite that expression like this:

```
ln(n!/(n-v)!v!) = ln(n!) - ln((n-v)!) - ln(v!)
```

But

```
(n-v)! = gamma(n-v+1)
n! = gamma(n+1)
v! = gamma(v+1)
```

So

```
ln(n!/(n-v)!v!) = lngamma(n+1) - lngamma(n-v+1) - lngamma(v+1)
```

You can find an implemenation for `lngamma` in Numerical Recipes.

`lngamma` returns a double, so it'll fit even for larger values.

It should go without saying that you'll take `exp()` of both sides to get the original expression you want back.

Answer (score 3):

@duffymo idea looked like too much fun to ignore: use `lgamma()` from `<math.h>`.

Results past maybe `x=1e15`, start to lose the trailing significant digits..  Still fun to be able to get `1000000.0!`.

```
void factorial_expo(double x, double *significand, double *expo) {
    double y = lgamma(x+1);
    const static double ln10 = 2.3025850929940456840179914546844;
    y /= ln10;
    double ipart;
    double fpart = modf(y, &ipart);
    if (significand) *significand = pow(10.0, fpart);
    if (expo) *expo = ipart;
}

void facttest(double x) {
  printf("%.1f!  =  ", x);
  double significand, expo;
  factorial_expo(x, &significand, &expo);
  int digits = expo > 15 ? 15 : expo;
  if (digits < 1) digits++;
  printf("%.*fe%.0f\n", digits, significand, expo);
}


int main(void) {
  facttest(0.0);
  facttest(1.0);
  facttest(2.0);
  facttest(6.0);
  facttest(10.0);
  facttest(69.0);
  facttest(1000000.0);
  return 0;
}

0.0!  =  1.0e0
1.0!  =  1.0e0
2.0!  =  2.0e0
6.0!  =  7.20e2
10.0!  =  3.628800e6
69.0!  =  1.711224524281441e98
1000000.0!  =  8.263931668544735e5565708
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with such long numbers as `59!` in simple way.
However you can use special `C` libraries which are working with long numbers bigger than 8 bytes, for example [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Are there any other ways? Thanks

Comment: The other way is mentioned by @duffymo but it will not give you exact number but only something like `1.3868311854568983573793901972039e+80` I guess. As standard calculators do.

Comment: I don't need the exact number. Just 15 or 16 decimal points..that's all@@

Comment: _You can't work with such long numbers as 59!_  are you certain?

Comment: Can you represent `59!` as simple integer and use default operators with it? I guess, you can't.